# Server side data fetch with react-router

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am rendering my React-router on server in my express app.
here is my code

```
app.use((req, res) => {

match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
console.log(renderProps)
if (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error.message)
} else if (redirectLocation) {
  res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
} else if (renderProps) {
  let component = renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps}/>);

  var html = renderToStaticMarkup(body(null,
      div({id: 'content', dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html:component}}),
      script({src: '/js/main.js'})
  ))
  res.end(html)
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  })
});
```

and it works.I can route without refresh.
but how i can refer to my express routes to make a queries to my database before my component will be rendered (not ajax queries)..

Answer (score 1):

You can query your database and use a callback which captures the variables you need to respond to the web request, e.g. `res`.
Alternatively, you can use generators to `yield` the result from your database.
Your solution will really matter on what database and library you're using.

Here's an example:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
let connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

// ...

app.use((req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) res.status(500).send(error.message);
    else if (redirectLocation) res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    else if (renderProps) {
      connection.query('SELECT 2 + 2 AS sample', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
        else {
          let fromDatabase = rows[0].sample;
          let component = renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
          let html = renderToStaticMarkup(body(
            null,
            div({ id: 'content', dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: component } }),
            script({ src: '/js/main.js' })
          ));
          res.end(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
  });
});

// ...
```

Comment: thanx for answer i will try it.but what if i need make different queries which depends on routes like if i will go to /users it must get all users...if i will go to /user/1 it will get a user where id equals 1....in your example i can make one select query.

Comment: Are you using express? If your route is, for example, `app.get('/user/:id', ...)` you can access the id via `req.params.id`. You can then query using this value.

Comment: Yes I am using Express.but you didn't understand) how can I refer to my Express routes from react router?

Comment: I put my Express routes to routes/api folder because when i refer to /users in browser it throws json response from Express route ..now I want  refer to my /api/users express route and get data from it when I am going to /users route of react.sorry for my english I think you understand me.